# "Main" YARA rule matches files that seem to not satisfy the private rule from the same ruleset

Tags: yara

I run several rulesets using the VirusTotal "hunting" feature and I use `private` YARA rules to filter out false positives. For example:

```
private rule isDex
{
    meta:
        description = "To filter out DEX files that fire many FPs"

    strings:
        $magicbytes = {64   65  78  0A}

    condition:
        $magicbytes at 0 

}
```

I refer to this rule with a `not` statement in another rule. This works as intended, I no longer get alerted on DEX files containing the strings I match on.

But another rule, that I refer to using the `and` statement, is being ignored. I also wrote another ruleset using that rule and I get the same results - the private rule is ignored and I am alerted on files matching the `$a` string, but not satisfying the `isClassified` rule

```
global private rule isClassified
{

    meta:
        description = "to detect files with classification label"

    strings:
        $p1 = "internal only" ascii wide nocase fullword
        $p2 = "confidential" ascii wide nocase fullword
        $p3 = "private" ascii wide nocase fullword
        $p4 = "secret" ascii wide nocase fullword

    condition:
        any of them

}


rule DLFakeCompanyName
{
    meta:
        date = "2017-02-20"
        state = "edited 2x, testing"
        //to do: check for datasize, file format, keywords

    strings:
        $a = "fakecompanyname" nocase ascii wide fullword

    condition:
        any of them
}
```

I tried both options, `global private` and just `private`, no difference. VT detects no syntax errors in neither of the rulesets. I have never encountered this problem before, and that's why it confuses me - some private rules are accepted but others are ignored.

Is this an issue with VirusTotal (that's the only place where I use YARA rules) itself? Or am I missing something while writing the rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually contacted VT support regarding this and apparently I missed a thing.

Since the rule is `private`, the strings it matches are not getting highlighted in the VT intelligence preview, only the strings from `DLFakeCompanyName` are highlighted. But both rules are actually met, if one checks the matched files manually.